# How to split the values in a map in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I have a map that has values that comes from multiple different columns in the database. The values have underscores in between. For example,

```
newMap("A", 23_null_12_09asfA)
```

Here, 23 comes from column A and null from column B and so on. Now, consider a map that has 20 values. I want to know how to split these values into arrays or how to split and store them?

Comment: "split all at once and put it in a data-frame" - what do you mean? Can you show an example of the desired output? And what's the purpose of using DataFrames if the entire collection has just 20 records, DataFrames are useful to distributively process large collections and will only create unnecessary overhead for small collections.

Comment: The entire collection has more than 50,000 records but, I was using 20 as an example.

Comment: I'll make it more clear. I have a value like this 23_null_23dA. I want to split these values, store them and want to perform a check with the original values.

Comment: please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43807122/edit) your post to include these details and _an example for the desired output_.

Answer (score 0):

```
val baseRDD=sc.parallelize(List(("john","1_abc_2"),("jack","3_xyz_4")))
val sRDD = baseRDD.map(x=> x._2.split("_"))
val resultDF=sRDD.toDF
resultDF.show
```

|[1, abc, 2]|
|[3, xyz, 4]|